# The origin of one of the usages of 狼{おおかみ}

Tags: words, etymology

I was watching the anime [かんなぎ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannagi%3a_Crazy_Shrine_Maidens), and heard the following line:

> 男はみんな[狼]{おおかみ}だわ！
>   "Men are all wolves!"

I was curious as to what it means to call someone a "wolf", so looked 狼 up in [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E7%8B%BC&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=02166200) and it came up with "someone who feigns being gentle, but in reality is a terrifying person" in the 2nd definition.

But why exactly did 狼 come to have this connotation? Does it have similar origins to the English phrase ["a wolf in sheep's clothing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_in_Sheep%27s_Clothing)? Or something else?

Comment: Is it really specific to japanese culture? What about the `Little Red Riding Hood`.

Comment: @oldergod does calling someone a "wolf" in English really have connotations of feigning being gentle? (I've never heard it used that way, but it might...) But I guess that was why I was asking - to confirm whether that was/wasn't the case that it is specific to Japanese, and whether it might have similar roots to other languages etc (hence why I asked whether it has similar origins to the idiom "a wolf in sheep's clothing".)

Comment: When I hear 男は狼,... it sounds to me like ... "guys are all スケベ so 年頃の女の子 have to be careful." (Cf. 「送り狼」and this old song http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltMCHeBXYEY)　英語でも、そういうニュアンスがありますか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it have similar origins to the English phrase "a wolf in sheep's clothing"?

Yes. A better dictionary would confirm that.
From 日本国語大辞典:

> 狼, 2: (**「狼に衣」のことわざから**) うわべはやさしくよそおっていて実は凶悪な人。特に、破戒僧の異称。

Early citations for this are from c. 1780. Early citations for 狼に衣 may be found from 1638. Thus, the chronology is also in order.

Answer (score 2):

Although Daijisen lists 狼{おおかみ}に衣{ころも} as a separate definition #3, from searching I think that it comes from that proverb.

Looking at [this page](http://www.geocities.jp/tomomi965/ko-jien01/a17.html) for example, it says that proverb means "an atrocious, merciless person, but only outward appearances of dressing as (feigning) being a good, kind-hearted person", so I think that's likely where it comes from.

---

Further to this, there's also the proverb [鬼{おに}に衣{ころも}](http://www.nohmask21.com/oni/prover_j.html), which has two meanings, one of which seems the same as that of 狼に衣, so it might be that 狼に衣 comes from 鬼に衣 (though I can't find any hard evidence which came earlier out of the two). It comes from an 鬼 (demon) wearing priest's garb (僧衣{そうい}).